How to automatically adjust column and row widths in excel every time?
Inquiry
I am interested in finding out a keyboard shortcut (or VBA macro) that will enable excel workbooks that I work with, to automatically adjust column widths and row widths.
Concerning automatically adjusting row widths, say I have a cell enabled as wrapped text. Furthermore, let's say a particular cell now requires adjustment of that column; this could imply that the row height may need to be adjusted to be shorter (or taller).
LINK
I actually first contacted Microsoft; the following link is when I asked a question to Microsoft in a discussion forum.
Link: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-automatically-adjust-column-widths-in-excel/f88abb8b-7e65-40e6-8a03-83decab25420?messageId=24299486-63c2-4fa7-b693-a6ecd94d576d
Please refer to this link to see how far I was able to get.
WHAT I HAVE DONE
After a representative from Microsoft replied to my question, I was given a code.
I was given a macro code, and I tried it, and this did indeed work. I saved a trial excel workbook as a macro-enabled workbook.
However, one keyboard shortcut that doesn't operate when I apply the macro is control + Z (the undo function). I'm assuming there is possibly other keyboard shortcuts that may not function with the macro enabled code I was given.
After a back and forth with Microsoft representatives, I was told that it may be in my best interest to go to stack overflow.
CONCLUSION
I am curious about a code that will automatically (and permanently) adjust column AND row widths, and simultaneously, ensure all traditional keyboard shortcuts still function (such as control + Z).
I am not sure if my inquiry pertains VBA or macro (I am not sure if there is a different, and what is the difference).
I was able to find one discussion that enables a code for row widths; however, I'm looking for a code to also complete this for column widths, and possibly have a larger code (since it may define my inquiry for automatically adjust column AND row widths).

Use GUI default methods? Select all cells by one click on the Select All button (the square top left at left of the column letters and at top of the row numbers). Then double click any of the dividing lines between column letters to auto fit all columns. Then double click any of the dividing lines between row numbers to auto fit all rows.

If you found a post with that enables a code for row widths adapt it to the columns also. If you are stuck then edit your question with the code you have the problem. Members of SO can help further. An idea: to place it in Worksheet_Change event.

FYI all details need to be here, in your question; nobody should need to visit an external site to figure out what you've done, or to see any of your code. Also, the entirety of your question (which isn't a programming question) only tells the story about you getting some code, and being directed to come here. Please take the [tour], read [ask], and about providing a [mcve]

Your macro is
Sub SizeAutofit()
    Cells.Rows.AutoFit
    Cells.Columns.AutoFit
End Sub

To get the quick access method, click on "Customize Quick Access Toolbar" and select "More Commands".
Select "Macros" in "Choose commands from:", select "SizeAutofit" and click "Add".
To have the feature available everywhere, save it in the personal macro book.


Good solution. But still, running this macro also creates a new undo chain and all previous possible undo actions in the previous undo chain are lost. So the requirement "ensure all traditional keyboard shortcuts still function (such as control + Z). I" is not fulfilled. Not that it could be fulfilled without using much more extensive VBA code to retain the previous undo chain.


"ensure all traditional keyboard shortcuts still function (such as control + Z). I" is expressed absolutely wrong if it means that you described. 2) The requirement you asked can't be fulfilled in Microsoft Excel by its design.

